# Tensorflow: Replace all values in tensor with smallest or largest value

Tags: tensorflow

I want to replace all values within a tensor with the smallest entry:

```
[1,-2,3,4,-4] -> [-4,-4,-4,-4,-4]
```

Right now I am doing

```
x = tf.random_normal([1,5], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.reduce_min(x) + 0.0*x
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's more efficient on both CPU and GPU if you do explicit initialization with [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) and not implicit broadcasting with addition. See benchmarks below. This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_normal([1,5], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.fill( tf.shape( x ), tf.reduce_min(x) )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( [ x, y ] )
    for v in res:
        print( v )
```

will output

> [[-1.9890205  -0.20791222  0.6901897   0.5605381   0.93578804]]
>   [[-1.9890205 -1.9890205 -1.9890205 -1.9890205 -1.9890205]]

as desired (numbers are random, but the second row has the minimum of the first one repeated in the same shape.)

---

#### Benchmarks

On my local computer the [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) version took 0.305 seconds vs. 1.479 for the original on the GPU and 0.191 vs. 1.923 on the CPU for a tensor shaped `[ 10000, 10000 ]`.

The [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) version took 0.082 seconds vs. 0.610 seconds for the original version on https://colab.research.google.com on the CPU, and 0.287 vs. 0.874 seconds respectively on the GPU.

Here is the code I used for the benchmark:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import time

with tf.device( "/gpu:0"):
    # x and m are in variables and calculated first so that the timing only measures
    # the fill vs. broadcast operation
    x = tf.Variable( tf.random_normal( [ 10000, 10000 ], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32 ) )
    m = tf.Variable( 0. )
    m_calc_op = tf.assign( m, tf.reduce_min( x ) )
    y1 = tf.fill( tf.shape( x ), m )
    y2 = m + 0.0 * x

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    sess.run( m_calc_op ) 
    #res = sess.run( [ y1, y2 ] ) # run it once

    start = time.clock()
    #for i in xrange( 10 ):
    res = sess.run( [ m, y1 ] )
    end = time.clock()
    print ( end - start, "m=", res[ 0 ] )

    start = time.clock()
    #for i in xrange( 10 ):
    res = sess.run( [ m, y2 ] )
    end = time.clock()
    print ( end - start, "m=", res[ 0 ] )
```

Note that I commented out the 10x repetition because it started giving unreasonably low values, maybe there is some optimization that the calculation is not rerun if the inputs didn't change. I enlarged the tensor instead.